# intel_rapl driver does not support CPU family 6 model 28

Tags: boot, drivers, cpu, operating-systems

I am trying to install *Remix OS* on my eMachines **eM250** KAV60, but at boot time that error pops up. I've tried to do other stuff but it just keeps loading indefinitely. I can provide more info, just ask for it. Or If you could point me out to another light OS that I can install on my underpowered PC, that'll be great!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (HP Mini 110)
*Burn iso with any tool, the boot to resident mode, before selecting Resident Mode press TAB and delete (SRC= DATA=) to end, then type INSTALL=1
*
https://forum.xda-developers.com/remix/remix-os/install-remix-os-main-os-dual-boot-t3419875

Answer (score -1):

i was not able to find this (SRC=DATA=)

while booting i pressed esc for menu
then before selecting resident mode i pressed "c" for command line
there i typed install=1*

and then it worked

:D